# Setting generator to specific value

Tags: java, jdbc, firebird

I"m converting a database and I need to set a generator to a value prior to generating new numbers.

Say the generator is called gtest. I've tried the following:

```
PreparedStatement nrps = csource.prepareStatement("alter sequence gtest restart with 100");
```

and

```
PreparedStatement nrps = csource.prepareStatement("set gopdracht to 100");
```

Option 1 gives me invalid syntax and option 2 gives unkown system variable.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which Firebird version do you use? `ALTER SEQUENCE` was added in Firebird 2.0. Also note that your second statement should be `SET GENERATOR gopdracht TO 100` (note the addition of `GENERATOR`). See http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-ddl-sequence.html

Comment: I've changed it accordingly, but it still gives me Unknown system variable 'generator'.
I'm using Firebird 2.1 with Jaybird 2.1 as driver.

Comment: Is the database ODS 11.1 or an older ODS version? Some features of Firebird only work if the database has been upgraded (by a backup and restore)

Comment: ODS 11.2 is the version.

Comment: If it is ODS 11.2, then you are using Firebird 2.5, not 2.1.

Comment: Oh my bad, I assumed Jaybird and Firebird lined up. I checked it, yes it's 2.5 indeed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49875/discussion-between-difusio-and-mark-rotteveel)

Comment: Is it by any chance a dialect 1 (instead of dialect 3) database?

Comment: Dialect 3. Do i need to connect to a different database then my own with data maybe?

Comment: Please include the stacktraces of the exceptions you get; I am beginning to suspect you are using a connection to a non-firebird database as there is no Firebird error message "Unknown system variable" (that is however a MySQL error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am beginning to suspect you are using a connection to a non-firebird database as there is no Firebird error message *"Unknown system variable"* (that is however a MySQL error).

I have tested it with Jaybird 2.2.4 on Firebird 2.5 and both [`ALTER SEQUENCE ... RESTART WITH ...`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-sequence-alter) and [`SET GENERATOR ... TO ...`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-sequence-setgen) work without error.

I used the following sample program:

```
private static final String fileName = "D:/data/db/alterseq.fdb";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FBManager manager = new FBManager();
    manager.setCreateOnStart(true);
    manager.setDropOnStop(true);
    manager.setUserName("sysdba");
    manager.setPassword("masterkey");
    manager.setFileName(fileName);
    manager.start();
    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost/" + fileName, "sysdba", "masterkey")) {
        try (Statement ddlStmt = con.createStatement()) {
            ddlStmt.execute("CREATE SEQUENCE seq_test");
        }
        try (PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(
                "ALTER SEQUENCE seq_test RESTART WITH 100")) {
            pstmt.execute();
        }
        try (PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(
                "SET GENERATOR seq_test TO 200")) {
            pstmt.execute();
        }
    } finally {
        manager.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: You where absolutely right in your comment. I accidentally had my ctarget connection connect to my source database wich was MySql. Problem resolved! Thank you for your extensive help. Bedankt.